# Determine the truth value of each statement, assuming that x, y, and z are real numbers.

Tags: logic, quantifiers

For all x in R, there exist y in R:y^3 =x

There exist y in R, for all x in R: y^3 = x

I am not quite sure what each is asking for.

Comment: "I am not quite sure what each is asking for": You're just being asked to determine if these statements are true... Let's look at the first one. Is it true that for all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$, there exists $y$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $y^3 = x$? Ok, if I pick an arbitrary real number $x$, can you find a real number $y$ such that $y^3 = x$?

Comment: You should learn some MathJax/LaTeX and use that to format your questions/answers here. They would look much better.

Comment: It is asking for the truth value which would make them truth 
for example for the 1st one I said:
using 1
1^3 = 1 so that would make it true. 
But I have issue with second 1

Comment: That's not a correct argument for 1). Just because it holds for 1, doesn't mean it's true. It needs to hold for _all_ $x\in\mathbb R$

Comment: Yes, but it is asking to determine the truth value. So I am assuming that it means that you find a value which makes it true. Is that a wrong assumption?

Comment: Taking $x = 1$ and $y = 1$ makes the formula $y^3 = x$ true. But you can't just ignore the quantifiers like that! You're asked to determine the truth value of the whole statement "For all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$, there exists $y$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $y^3 = x$". And the meaning of this statement is what I wrote in my previous comment.

Comment: Regarding the second one: Can you give me a real number $y$ such that for *every* real number $x$, $y^3 = x$? All you have to do is think about what the words mean.

Comment: Alex, iso the "truth value" is whether it is true or false then?

Comment: got the reasoning Alex.

Answer (score 3):

The first one says every real number has a real cube root. 
The second one says all real numbers have the same cube roots.

You can decide which one is true.

Comment: Interesting. Can you break down how you read the second 1 please.